# How do you correctly shorten "ask her what's her hair color"?

Tags: grammar

How do you correctly shorten "ask her what's her hair color"? I thought you can just say "ask her her hair color", but then I find it weird, so I don't know if it's correct.

For example:

> She asked her what's her hair color. She replied yellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first choice, "Ask her what's her hair color." has the words in non-standard order, but for informal speech it's quite acceptable.

The usual word order ("inverted") would be "Ask her what her hair color is." That would always be considered grammatical at any level of formality.

"Ask her her hair color." is also idiomatic and easily understood. It sounds fine, not weird (to me).

Comment: Also, e.g. ask her her age, height, date of birth, etc.

Comment: Or *she asked **for** her hair colour.*